# vi substitution different behaviour from vim

Tags: vi

I am trying to substitute newline characters with a word in classical vi (in arch linux). The substitute command looks like this:

:%s/\n/word/g

which does work in vim. The file I am working on is the result of a copy / paste from Calc (coming from a csv from a datawarehouse program).

VIM output is that lines are substituted (resulting in a very loooong line which is a command I have to feed to another program). 
I tested this in Windows and Linux on VIM.

Vi output on the same file is: "Substitute pattern match failed"

The vi version I am using is the default one in Arch: Version 4.0 (gritter) 12/25/06

Which is classical vi.

It's not like I could not do that in VIM, but why isn't this working in vi? Is there a way to make this work? I tried to look for a solution, but did not come across anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vi` uses [`ex` regular-expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_58), which are mostly [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), and do not require C-style escape sequences.  The [`join` commend from `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.htmltag_20_40_13_22) can be used instead, with a `!` to prevent modification (it normally adjusts spaces).

```
:%j!
```

Substitute commands can be used to simulate replacing the newlines.

```
:2,$s/^/start
:1,$-s/$/end
:%j!
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is very useful and informative.